# OOTB web part filter based on user group

Tags: ootb

I have one list with Title and AssignedTo field (Person or Group) that allows only People (not group). I want to show OOTB web part (e.g. List view web part, content query web part etc. anything is accepted) which shows all data of current user group.
E.g. List having 4 items(Title, AssingedTo) as below

1. Test1 User A
2. Test2 User B
3. Test3 User C
4. Test4 User D

User A,B,C are in one group called "Marketing" and User D in "Sales"
Now User A log in so he can see first 3 items because User A,B,C are in same group.

I am not sure how to fulfill this.

Answer (score 0):

- Audiences

For showing specific web parts to specific users based on some property you may need to leverage [Audiences](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-SharePoint-Online-audiences-1806ec78-1d4e-4620-8a89-89d6a38c9c33). In that scenario, only users that share a certain property, e.g. Department will see the given webpart.

[image]

- Filtering list view

Another option is using [Me] when creating a list view. How exactly it would be used depends on the columns and settings of your list.
[image]

- People Search

Another option is a filter - based PeopleSearch. Choose local People Results and configure a filter based on the property (e.g. Department):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Grisha. I had already these solutions in my mind but none of them satisfy my requirement. I found below logic (query) for xsltview webpart working but I don't know how to make ID (GroupID) dynamic

<Or>
            <Membership Type="SPGroup" ID="1768">
              <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/>
            </Membership>
            <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo">
              </FieldRef>
              <Value Type="Integer">
                <UserID/>
              </Value>
            </Eq>
          </Or>